# How can we know if class of jar version or the local copy is being called at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, vs-web-application-project

I have same class file in my workspace as well as in jar file also (Which i had imported )
How can i know which file is being called at run time ??

I am confused because, in Eclipse, when i press Open Declaration on the instance, it shows the jar version .
And when I kept some system outs on to the local copy, they are being called ??

Please tell me how can i know what file is being called ??

I was talking about these code:

```
Props.getProperty(clientID + ".MetaPI", true);
```

This Props class exists in both the jar and in local copy also.

Answer (score 1):

whatever is first on your classpath should be called, in ideal case that should be the classes folder hence your class file.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start your application with java -verbose. This logs which classes are loaded by the class loader

Answer (score 0):

This probably might help:

```
this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

Comment: @astrograph, sorry for posting the same answer. Probably forgot to refresh the page...